# How to hide the full directory when serving static files with Apache

Tags: django, apache, static

I am using Django and Apache.

I am serving the static files with Apache. It works well, the problem is, when a user go to the url `http://urlOfMySite.com/static`, he can see the whole directory and navigate in it.

I'm using :  `Alias /static /var/www/MySite/app/app/static` in Apache VirtualHost to serve static files.

Is there any way to hide it from user? (make the static files accessible, but not the full directory browsable).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is about the apache server itself, you need to disable indexing for that folder with "Options -Indexes" inside the "directory" clause to specify which folder you want to apply this command. More info:https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings#Directory_Listings

Btw, this is odd, by default, when I deploy using Apache, I don't need this =/.

Comment: Hmm this is weird, I didn't change this. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that I installed a ftp server as well?

Comment: Dunno... ftp shouldn't affect apache2 config.. try to disable it but have no idea. By setting the "options -indexes" as I've told you it should work but, I have no idea why you need this (by default it should raise a 404 error). Btw, edit your question and place your urls file, do you have something pointing static?

Comment: Yes it works with your solution. I've put it for the Directory /, to be 100% sure nothing will be indexed on my server. Thanks, hope someone will know why I needed this ^^